# How can I make each scanf working without skip

Tags: c, for-loop, struct, scanf

> I make the loop with gets and scanf. Actually I make the space for newline buffer. so I think each scanf works but when I input value to &books[ctr].cost compiler skip next 3 questions. I don't know why It work like this

books is structure variable

```
for (ctr = 0 ; ctr < 3 ; ctr++)
{
    printf("What is the name of the book #%d?\n", (ctr+1));
    gets(books[ctr].title);
    puts("Who is the author?  ");
    gets(books[ctr]. author);
    puts("How much did the book cost?  ");
    scanf("  $%f", &books[ctr].price);
    puts("How many pages in the book?  ");
    scanf("  %d", &books[ctr].pages);
    getchar( );
}
printf("\n\n Here is the collection of books : \n");
for (ctr = 0 ; ctr < 3 ; ctr ++)
{
    printf("#%d: %s by %s", (ctr+1), books[ctr].title, books[ctr].author);
    printf("\n It is %d pages and costs $%.2f", books[ctr].pages, books[ctr].price);
    printf("\n\n");
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. What happens *before* the code you show? What is the expected output? What is the actual output? And what input do you give the program?

Comment: Also please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Lastly, always check what `scanf` [***returns***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: thanks to advice I'll read that and ask again

Answer (score 0):

First of all, two suggestions:

- [Do not use `gets()` at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2173917), it's dangerous and deprecated.
- Also, [avoid using `scanf()` for direct user inputs](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html), it's not worth it.

Use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to take user input, and then convert to appropriate form using [`sscanf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf).

Comment: but this is my college assignment and It's example from my major textbook. so It must work with that code. I don't know why It's not working